# How to define a global instance of a php class?

Tags: php, class, instance, global

This is my code :

```
<?php
require_once 'classes/dbconnect.php';
$connector = new dbconnect();
pp();
function pp(){
$uid="0000007";
$table = $connector->query("SELECT * FROM tc_personal WHERE uid = '$uid'");
$tb = mysql_fetch_object($table);
print $tb->name;
}
?>
```

but this code will not work because the pp() function can't access the $connector.
How can i define a global variable as $connector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
require_once 'classes/dbconnect.php';
global $connector;
$connector = new dbconnect();
pp();
function pp(){
global $connector;
$uid="0000007";
$table = $connector->query("SELECT * FROM tc_personal WHERE uid = '$uid'");
$tb = mysql_fetch_object($table);
print $tb->name;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 9):

Surely better than using globals, even if not OOP

```
<?php 
require_once 'classes/dbconnect.php'; 
$connector = new dbconnect(); 
pp($connector); 

function pp($connector){ 
    $uid="0000007"; 
    $table = $connector->query("SELECT * FROM tc_personal WHERE uid = '$uid'"); 
    $tb = mysql_fetch_object($table); 
    print $tb->name; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks , The global is easier.

Comment: The global is also bad coding practise... easier !== better

Comment: Absolutely agreed with @MarkBaker, You should avoid globals as much as possible. This should be accepted one.